# extra datatype at the end of numpy array after apply dataframe method

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I am applying the following code to a `numpy` array:

```
mad_array = []
for j in data:
    df = pd.DataFrame(j)
    print(j)
    mad_array.append(df.mad())

print(mad_array)
```

The output array looks like this:

```
[0    10.0   dtype: float64, 
 0    18.875 dtype: float64, 
 0    18.375 dtype: float64]
```

Is there a way to strip out the extra `0` *(not sure where this is coming from)* and `datatype` property that is appended to the output, so my output array looks something like:

```
[10.0 18.875 18.375]
```

I'm not sure if this is a behavior from `numpy` or `DataFrame`.

Comment: Try `df.mad().values`.

Comment: That solved it. Please give a proper answer.

Comment: You have constructed a list of dataframes, which the print displays.  Would you rather have a list of lists, or maybe a list of numpy arrays?

Comment: Have you ever looked at the display of a dataframe?  The `df` or `df.mat()` alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.mad().values`, to return on the values of the series/dataframe.  The zeros are the from the index of the of the series/dataframe and the dtype is the string representation of the series/dataframe.  By converting the returned dataframe/series from the mad() method using the `values` attribute, you are only appending the values part of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment use

```
df.mad().values
```

to get rid of the `dataType` and `0 index`

Your `mad_array` array should now look like:

```
[array([10.]), array([18.875]), array([18.375])]
```

Choose first index of each of the array like this

```
(df.mad().values)[0]
```

Result

```
[10.0, 18.875, 18.375]
```